# Automatic check the checkbox when I Filled Out : App Script Gsheet

Tags: javascript

I create my own project own gsheet where is I want to create a Event in checkbox to automatically check if I choose one which is the NON COD its automatically check if i choose COD it wont uncheck the checkbox .

```
function checkBoxes() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DATA ENTRY');
  var range1 = ss.getRange('J2:J998');
  var range2 = ss.getRange('K2:K998');
  var values = range1.getValues();
  

  const numRows = range2.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range2.getNumColumns();
  
  

  for(let i = 1; i <=numRows; i++){
    for(let j = 1; j <= numCols; j++){
      let checkbox = range2.getCell(i,j);
      let tfValue = values[i-1][j-1];
      if(tfValue == "COD"){
        checkbox.uncheck();

      }
      else if (tfValue == "NON COD"){
        checkbox.check();
        
      }
    }
```

Im using for loop , but the problem its delay trigger the event , I want upon entry when I choose NON COD .